# Concat DataFarme instead of Printing (Python/for loop)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am desperately trying not return my result from a loop (Annual growth Rate) in a concatenated dataframe but the following loop just prints each dataframe out. This loop is in a function.

I appreciate any help.

```
for i in ODList:
    start_value = float(Grouped3[i].iloc[0])
    end_value = float(Grouped3[i].iloc[-1])
    num_periods = len(Grouped3)
    TopCAGR = pd.DataFrame({'Dest Code':[i],'CAGR':cagr(start_value, end_value, num_periods)})
    print (TopCAGR)
```

Thank you. Have a ncie weekend.

Max

Comment: see pandas merge, join, concatenate dataframe functions in the doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Thank you I did. But I am not able to concat in a for loop somehow.

Comment: Create a list, fill it in the loop and then after the loop insert it into your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use do apply on the data frame to get your result. Below is an example using a made up function cagr, but it should work as long as your function is valid:

```
def cagr(S,E,P): 
    return (E-S)/P 

Grouped3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,7],'C':[9,4,5]})
ODList = ['A','B']
```

Using concat:

```
TopCAGR=[]
for i in ODList:
    start_value = float(Grouped3[i].iloc[0])
    end_value = float(Grouped3[i].iloc[-1])
    num_periods = len(Grouped3)
    TopCAGR.append(pd.DataFrame({'Dest Code':[i],'CAGR':cagr(start_value, end_value, num_periods)}))

pd.concat(TopCAGR)
  Dest Code      CAGR
0         A  0.666667
0         B  1.000000
```

Using apply:

```
TopCAGR = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dest Code':ODList,
    'TopCAGR' : Grouped3[ODList].apply(lambda x:cagr(x.iloc[0],x.iloc[-1],len(x)))
})

  Dest Code   TopCAGR
A         A  0.666667
B         B  1.000000
```